# How to update www on cross-platform platform-centered Cordova workflow?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios, cordova-android

I need to make changes to my iOS and Android projects (e.g. add a VPN extension), so I'd like to explore the [platform-centered workflow](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/guide/overview/index.html#development-paths), which creates the native app once, and you work from there.

However, when we create the app, the www content gets inserted in the resources, and merged with other resources. But I want to share the www between Android and iOS, so I need to build it and re-insert it into the app. How can I replace www in the apps created with the platform-centered workflow?

I expected something similar to [plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/plugin_ref/plugman.html), which still allows me to update plugins after the app is created, but couldn't find anything for the www content specifically.